# onclick event in Apex:inputfeild is not calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, apexinputfield

not able to call javascript function from apex:inputfeild  in visualforce page

```
function getEmail(Emailfeild)
{

               alert('sam');
              var Email = document.getElementById(Emailfeild).value;
              Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                    
                 '{!$RemoteAction.RetrivialControllerExtension.getAction}',
                    Email, 
                    function(result, event){
                        if (event.status==true) {
                            if(result!=null){
                       document.getElementById('Email ID').innerHTML = 
         result.Email_ID__c;
     }
            }, 
            {escape: true}
        );
    }
```

VF page

```
<apex:pageblockSection columns="1">
    <div align="center">
       <apex:inputfield required="true" id="Emailfeild" onclick="getEmail('{!$Component.Emailfeild} )" value="{!IBI_TM_Applicants__c.Email_ID__c}">
         </apex:inputField> 
<apex:pageBlockSectionItem >
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE). Thank you for including code, but there is no actual question in your post. Please take the [Tour](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/tour) & look in the Help Center - especially [What topics can I ask about here?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) where it states, _'...a question post should include 1) A specific, detailed description of the issue ("it doesn’t work" is not enough to allow the community to help). plus ... 3) and/or the research and work you’ve done so far on the issue.'_ Please edit your question to add info.

Comment: Thank you - that is a good start. However, what exactly does it mean to say, "not able to call javascript function?" **>** Are you receiving an error? If so, edit again & include a screenshot or a copy/paste of the exact error text. **>** If you are not receiving an error, are you sure that the JavaScript is not being called? Maybe the JavaScript is not working as expected. Have you checked any debug logs? If so, edit again & include details. **>** If there are no errors and no logs, include any `alert`s or `console.log()`s or anything else you have tried to use to debug, and the results.

Comment: Aside from my answer, there's also a non-zero probability that you may have misspelled something. Make sure you're paying attention to variable and method names, and also note that JavaScript is cAsE-sEnSiTiVe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need to use ID values here, just use event.target:

```
<apex:inputfield required="true" onclick="getEmail(event)" value="{!IBI_TM_Applicants__c.Email_ID__c}">
```

---

```
function getEmail(event) {
    var email = event.target.value;
  // ... rest of code
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ,it worked for me